# Angular: Close a MatDialog

Tags: angular, typescript

I am opening a loading MatDialog when I make a HTTP request. However when I try to close it in the subscription of the call it doesnt close it.

What am I doing wrong?

```
      saveListOfSteps(isFormValid: boolean): void{

    if(isFormValid== false){
      alert("You have not filled out all fields in the form! Fix that first");
    }else{
      // show a loading dialog
      let dialogRefLoading = this.dialog.open(PopupComponent, {
        width: '250px',
        data: {
          data: ["Loading..."],
          showCloseButton: false},
      },    
      );
     dialogRefLoading.close;
     this.SelfServiceDetailsService.saveListOfSteps(this.validationSteps)
     .subscribe(response=>{
      dialogRefLoading.close;
       this.showSaveResultsDialog(response.body),
     error => alert("An error occured")});
    }

  }
```

Comment: You are missing parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`close` is function so you have to call it like

```
dialogRefLoading.close();
```

instead of

```
 dialogRefLoading.close;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defined `dialogRefLoading`  variable inside the else condition. It should be  declared globally . And `close()` is a function not property in `Dialog` class. So you should use `dialogRefLoading.close()` instead of `dialogRefLoading.close`

---

Try this below code instead of your code

```
saveListOfSteps(isFormValid: boolean): void {
    let dialogRefLoading = null;
    if (isFormValid == false) {
      alert("You have not filled out all fields in the form! Fix that first");
    } else {
      // show a loading dialog
      dialogRefLoading = this.dialog.open(PopupComponent, {
        width: '250px',
        data: {
          data: ["Loading..."],
          showCloseButton: false
        },
      },
      );          
      this.SelfServiceDetailsService.saveListOfSteps(this.validationSteps)
        .subscribe(response => {
          dialogRefLoading.close();
          this.showSaveResultsDialog(response.body),
            error => alert("An error occured")
        });
    }
  }
```